# Force to use 3G and WiFi is on?

Tags: cyanogenmod, wi-fi, nexus-4, 3g

Can I force android through settings to use 3G for all downloads when both WiFi and 3G are on?

The main reason why I am trying to achieve this is that I want to use WiFi only as a mean to connect to ADB (without use of USB).

I have Nexus 4 phone which runs Cyanogenmod 10.

Comment: That is built into Android, Wifi and 3G are mutually exclusive flip/flop. Cannot have both of them on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The Short Answer**

Nope, not possible, or at least *compicated & tedious*, because Android defaults to WiFi since it's generally faster, more reliable and has no data cap

**However**

You may want to look into [this app](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/08/08/combine-3g4g-and-wifi-to-download-and-destroy-your-data-cap-faster-than-ever/). While it requeires a rooted device, it allows you to leverage on both your WiFi & 3G to download at the same time.

**The Long Answer**

As t0mm13b has suggested (and I eagerly defer to him), if you're really serious about this and have the necessary expertise, you can

> modify the source code to remove the mutually exclusive flip/flop and also at the RIL layer

Unfortunately, I'm not qualified enough to do more than point you in the direction of the [Android Developer Page](https://developer.android.com/index.html) if you decide to go down this route.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will have to look for other alternative.

Comment: The app that you have referred to requires root, *Using both networks together requires root access (remember to say "authorize" to the superuser prompt).* and also *Using both connections is not supported on all devices / rom combinations.*, The real way to do this is to modify the source code to remove the mutually exclusive flip/flop and also at the RIL layer.